# Como capturar repetições de um determinado grupo com regex?

Tags: regex

Estou tentando capturar um determinado dado estruturado, e preciso que ele capture um determinado grupo enquanto houver possibilidades.

O formato do dado é o seguinte:

> foo01@chave1|valor1#chaveN|valorN

Aonde o primeiro grupo é composto por um valor alfa numérico, separando os demais grupos com o caracter `@`, o meu interesse é obter apenas o `foo01`  no primeiro grupo.

O segundo grupo é o que se repete, aonde Atributo e valor são separado por `|` e os demais atributos são separados por `#`, após isso não há mais informação apenas atributos no formato "chave1|valor1#chaveN|valorN".

Abaixo é possível ver o que eu comecei a fazer, mas não consegui fazer capturar todos os atributos de forma separada.

```js
const regex = /(^[a-zA-Z0-9_]*@)([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\|[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)/g;
const str = `foo01@chave1|valor1#chaveN|valorN`;
let m;

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }

  m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
    console.log(`Encontrado, grupo ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
  });
}
```

Nota: Está em js apenas pela facilidade de se adicionar o snippet

Gostaria de saber como faço para capturar todas as ocorrências de "chave1|valor1#chaveN|valorN" dentro de uma string independente da quantidade presente na string.

Comment: No caso, você precisa capturar todos os atributos de forma separada independente da quantidade presente na string? Entendi certo?

Comment: Exatamente, preciso que o grupo `([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\|[a-zA-Z0-9_]*)` seja capturado n vezes até o fim.
Estou preocupado com performance aqui, poderia fazer isso usando interação, mas acredito que expressão regular será bem mais performatica.

Comment: Não tenho certeza se regex suporta algo assim. Lembro de uma vez ter pesquisado uma solução parecida e não ter encontrado nada. Tive que tratar pelo JS mesmo.

Comment: Boa pergunta +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Como capturar repetições de um determinado grupo com regex?

**Existem 2 alternativas:**

- Use o recurso *[match previously named capture group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)* (encontre o grupo nomeado anteriormente), com ele você pode designar um nome para um grupo de captura e repetir sua captura diversas vezes usando quantificadores *greedy*, *lazy*, *possessive*, etc.
- Crie 2 grupos de captura, o primeiro para capturar a sequencia que deseja e um outro por fora, englobando somente o grupo de captura e um quantificador, no seu caso usaria um quantificar guloso (*greedy*)

**Resposta 1**

```
(?'foo'\w*)@(?'Todos_Atrib_Val'(?'Atrib_Val'\w*\|\w*#{0,1})(?'Atrib_Val_Recursivo'\g'Atrib_Val')*)
```

Eu entendo que seja desesperador ver um código de Regex tão grande, porém ele é muito mais fácil de ser lido, uma vez colocado no site regex101 ou isolando seus grupos de captura nomeados e analisando 1 a 1, fica muito mais fácil a manutenção do código e leitura por outros programadores.
[Aqui você pode ver essa regex em ação](https://regex101.com/r/IAaihA/5), recomendo que olhe no painel "Match Information" e note como fica organizada a linha de pensamento.

**Resposta 2**

```
(\w*)@((\w*\|\w*#{0,1})*)
```

Aqui está a mesma linha de pensamento, porém sem nomear grupos e sem uso do recurso de captura de grupos anteriores.

- Grupo 1 para capturar a sequencia antes do `@`
- Grupo 2 que irá capturar tudo que o grupo 3 encontrar, armazenando todos os resultados de forma gulosa.
- Grupo 3 que identifica a sequencia e captura chave1|valor1# N vezes, porém só armazena a ultima.

[Você pode checar que seu funcionamento é igual ao primeiro exemplo aqui.](https://regex101.com/r/IAaihA/2)

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa capturar tudo em uma única expressão regular mesmo?

Eu acredito que consegui algo próximo do que você precisa aqui com esta. Deixei o @ e # de fora:

```
const regex = /(^[\d\w_]*)?[@|#]([\d\w_]*\|[\d\w_]*)/g
```

Mas acredito que nesse caso um split() ficaria bem mais simples de entender tudo.

```
var campos = str.split('@');
var inicio = campos[0];
var lista = campos[1].split('#');

console.log(inicio, lista);
```

Answer (score 2):

O jeito que conheço é com split()...

```
var arrayStr = str.split(/(@|#|\|)/)
```

Isso cria uma variável array que terá os elementos separados por @, # ou |

E para pegar:

```
arrayStr[0]
arrayStr[1]
```